# Issues exporting SSRS to CSV with textbox names

Tags: csv, reporting-services

So I'm trying to export my SSRS to .CSV. The layout of my report is like this: [image: As you can see, many expressions and whatnot]

Everything does work fine, on my VS. However, when comes the time to generate it I get this:

[image]

I've read a few other post on Stack Overflow about how I can change my SSRS config for noheaders and ASCII. Thing is, people tried to set column names programatically, but here I only have expressions for cell contents and a current layout. Is there a way to make my CSV lay out look like my reportbuilder layout? Or is my problem the same as when people try to set the column programatically

Comment: If you export to XLSX rather than CSV you should see SSRS best attempt at producing your report output in the same layout.  There are many gotchas that will produce undesirable / unexpected output in the XLSX, but there are many articles on the web that enumerate most the things to avoid and how to workaround.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot export XLSX first. Its for customers, I do have an option for it but its taking way too much memory. I was looking for a way to handle it , was hoping there was one

Answer (score 2):

For each data field you want to export set the DataElementName to match the field title and set the value to the DataElementOutput to output the field.
For the header textboxes set the DataElementOutput to NoOutput.

For more detail check the following microsoft link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255251.aspx